# Why does using HAVING eliminate outputs when the same condition works in an IF statement?

Tags: mysql, sql

**Context**

I am trying to solve the HackerRank problem at the link below:

https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/challenges/problem

I am focusing on excluding the unwanted data from the output. The problem states:

> If more than one student created the same number of challenges and
> the count is less than the maximum number of challenges created, then
> exclude those students from the result.

I have split this up into two conditions:

1. The student will be included if they had the maximum count of challenges (regardless of how many students achieved this count) OR
2. The student will be included if their challenge count is unique

**What I've tried**

I am focusing on the first condition. This is the query I've come up with:

```
SELECT h.hacker_id, h.name, COUNT(c.challenge_id) as cnt
FROM Hackers as h
LEFT JOIN Challenges as c ON h.hacker_id = c.hacker_id
GROUP BY h.hacker_id, h.name, c.challenge_id
HAVING /* Either the max, or things that are not duplicates*/ 
    COUNT(c.challenge_id) = MAX((SELECT COUNT(c1.challenge_id) FROM Challenges as c1))
ORDER BY cnt DESC, hacker_id ASC
```

This results in no output to stdout.

The issue is with the HAVING statement. I tried checking the conditional by querying just the MAX(...) statement:

```
SELECT MAX((SELECT COUNT(c1.challenge_id) FROM Challenges as c1))
FROM Challenges
```

I get an output.

Then I tried using the whole conditional in an IF() statement:

```
SELECT IF(
    COUNT(c.challenge_id) = MAX((SELECT COUNT(c1.challenge_id) FROM Challenges as c1)),
    CONCAT(COUNT(c.challenge_id), ', it works',
    'No good'
)
FROM Challenges as c
```

This returns the same max value as the test of my MAX() clause.

Can anyone explain to me why the full query, with the conditional in the HAVING clause, returns no output?

Comment: You typically `GROUP BY` the same columns you `SELECT`, _except_ those who are arguments to set functions. I.e. try `GROUP BY h.hacker_id, h.name`.

Comment: The subquery returns the total number of non-null challenge_id rows in that table.

Comment: You're not grouping the MAX by hacker ID.

Comment: @jarlh I think I see what you mean about the MAX statement. The statement as written in my question above counts ALL the challenges, and then takes the MAX of that number (which is the number). That also explains why the IF statement test I used returned true. I am trying to salvage my statement, but adding a `GROUP BY c1.hacker_id` statement now returns the maximum for each group, which is not what I want. Do you guys have any tips on how I might salvage this statement? Or how to write a better one from the get-go?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you almost got it. A few changes and addition to your current query can return the correct result.

Your original query:

```
SELECT h.hacker_id, h.name, COUNT(c.challenge_id) as cnt
FROM Hackers as h
LEFT JOIN Challenges as c ON h.hacker_id = c.hacker_id
GROUP BY h.hacker_id, h.name, c.challenge_id /*remove c.challenge_id from the group by */
HAVING  /*remove HAVING from the query*/
    COUNT(c.challenge_id) = MAX((SELECT COUNT(c1.challenge_id) FROM Challenges as c1))
/*take the MAX function and modify the subquery by adding group by, order by and limit then move it to SELECT*/
ORDER BY cnt DESC, hacker_id ASC /*remove this for now*/
```

After modification of the above, you'll get something like this:

```
#1st sub-query
SELECT h.hacker_id, h.name, COUNT(*) AS cnt,
       MAX((SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM Challenges GROUP BY hacker_id ORDER BY cnt DESC LIMIT 1)) AS mxc
FROM Hackers AS h
LEFT JOIN Challenges AS c ON h.hacker_id = c.hacker_id
GROUP BY h.hacker_id, h.name
```

Make the query above as a sub-query then construct another query to be used as validation on any `hacker_id` that have the same `challenges_created` count. This is the sub-query:

```
#2nd sub-query
SELECT hacker_id, COUNT(*) cnt FROM Challenges GROUP BY hacker_id
```

Then use `LEFT JOIN` on the 1st & 2nd query like this

```
SELECT A.hacker_id, A.name, A.cnt AS 'challenges_created' FROM
(SELECT h.hacker_id, h.name, COUNT(*) AS cnt,
       MAX((SELECT COUNT(c1.challenge_id) AS cnt FROM Challenges AS c1 GROUP BY hacker_id ORDER BY cnt DESC LIMIT 1)) AS mxc
FROM Hackers AS h
LEFT JOIN Challenges AS c ON h.hacker_id = c.hacker_id
GROUP BY h.hacker_id, h.name) A 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT hacker_id, COUNT(*) cnt FROM Challenges GROUP BY hacker_id) V 
ON A.cnt=V.cnt AND A.hacker_id <> V.hacker_id AND V.cnt < A.mxc
WHERE V.cnt IS NULL
ORDER BY A.cnt DESC, A.hacker_id ASC
```

Lets observe the `ON` condition on this part of the `LEFT JOIN`. So `ON A.cnt=V.cnt AND A.hacker_id <> V.hacker_id AND V.cnt < A.mxc` literally mean "the count is the same but hacker id is not while the second result count is less than the max count from the first result". Add `WHERE V.cnt IS NULL` to return only the one doesn't match with the `ON` condition and finalize it with the `ORDER BY`.

I obtained the data used in the the challenge and created a fiddle from it here : https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=be99385a91d809b3daeaeb1ca3f54e0d

Btw,

"The main difference between WHERE and HAVING clause comes when used together with GROUP BY clause, In that case WHERE is used to filter rows before grouping and HAVING is used to exclude records after grouping.

Read more: [https://www.java67.com/2019/06/difference-between-where-and-having-in-sql.html#ixzz6b01iR3NB"](https://www.java67.com/2019/06/difference-between-where-and-having-in-sql.html#ixzz6b01iR3NB%22)

Comment: Very cool! I like the idea of selecting from the subquery. This makes the most intuitive sense to me. Your answer also continues in the vein of my attempt, so appreciate that too. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The challenge was actually challenging :-). It took more time than I expected. Here is my solution below -

```
SELECT Tx.hacker_id, 
       Tx.NAME, 
       Tx.challenges 
FROM   (SELECT h.hacker_id                    AS hacker_id, 
               h.NAME                         AS NAME, 
               Count(DISTINCT c.challenge_id) AS challenges 
        FROM   hackers h 
               LEFT JOIN challenges c 
                      ON h.hacker_id = c.hacker_id 
        GROUP  BY h.hacker_id, 
                  h.NAME 
        HAVING Count(DISTINCT c.challenge_id) = (SELECT Max(challenges) 
                                                 FROM 
               (SELECT 
                      h.hacker_id, 
                      Count(DISTINCT c.challenge_id) AS challenges 
                                                         FROM   hackers h 
                                                LEFT JOIN challenges c 
                                                       ON h.hacker_id = 
                                                          c.hacker_id 
                                                         GROUP  BY h.hacker_id) T 
                                                 ) 
        UNION 
        SELECT T1.hacker_id  AS hacker_id, 
               T1.NAME       AS NAME, 
               T1.challenges AS challenges 
        FROM   (SELECT h.hacker_id, 
                       h.NAME, 
                       Count(DISTINCT c.challenge_id) AS challenges 
                FROM   hackers h 
                       LEFT JOIN challenges c 
                              ON h.hacker_id = c.hacker_id 
                GROUP  BY h.hacker_id, 
                          h.NAME) T1 
               JOIN (SELECT T.challenges 
                     FROM   (SELECT h.hacker_id, 
                                    h.NAME, 
                                    Count(DISTINCT c.challenge_id) AS challenges 
                             FROM   hackers h 
                                    LEFT JOIN challenges c 
                                           ON h.hacker_id = c.hacker_id 
                             GROUP  BY h.hacker_id, 
                                       h.NAME) T 
                     GROUP  BY T.challenges 
                     HAVING Count(DISTINCT T.hacker_id) = 1) T2 
                 ON T1.challenges = T2.challenges) Tx 
ORDER  BY 3 DESC, 
          1;
```

Although the code looks long but the logic is quite simple. The upper part of the union computes those hacker_id and related info who submitted the maximum amount of chanllenges and the 2nd part of the union tackles to select only those hackers who have submitted non-max but unique number of challenges.

Comment: I think I've seen another solution that uses a union as well. I'll have to look into this more. Thanks for the response!

Comment: Thank you! I am actually intrigued by the other solution. If I describe it in my way - this problem consists of 3 distinct sets - X : hackers with max number of attempts, Y : hackers with unique number of attempts Z : hackers with non-unique number of attempts (compared to other hackers) but less than maximum number of attempts by a hacker. We have to find (X U Y) and the other solution does it beautifully by actually targeting set Z (join conds.) then cleverly use IS NULL on left join to find out Z’ or Universe - Z or X U Y. Whereas my solution attempts to find distinct sets X,Y & union them.